# Error When Passing Large Files to Server via AJAX POST Request (IIS 7, ASP.NET MVC 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is my first post on StackOverflow so I apologize in advance if my question is in an unconventional format. I have a form on an intranet site which allows the user to upload files by passing them to the server.The js function that passes the file to the server is below. This code works flawlessly on smaller files (tested up to 900kb), but a larger file (9mb) produces a 500 error ***without even reaching the server.***

```
function UploadDocument(customSectionId, evaluationSectionId) {
    if ($('#eval-attachment-modal-file')[0].files != null) {
        if (customSectionId != null && customSectionId == -1) {
            customSectionId = null;
        }
        if (evaluationSectionId != null && evaluationSectionId == -1) {
            evaluationSectionId = null;
        }
        var file = $('#eval-attachment-modal-file')[0].files[0];
        if (file) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("fileToUpload", file);
            fd.append("evalId", EvalId);
            fd.append("customSectionId", customSectionId);
            fd.append("evaluationSectionId", evaluationSectionId);
            fd.append("canUploadImages", @(Model.CanUploadImages ? "true" : "false"));
            fd.append("canUploadDocuments", @(Model.CanUploadDocuments ? "true" : "false"));
            $('#upload-file-button').hide();
            $('#upload-file-spinner').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UploadDocument")',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != null && response.success) {
                        $('#evaluation-attachment-grid').trigger('reloadGrid');
                        if (evaluationSectionId == @((int) EvaluationSection.ExecutiveSignature)) {
                            var checkbox = $('#ExecutiveSignatureSignedOff');
                            var dateFieldForCheckbox = $('#ExecutiveSignatureSignedOffDate');
                            if (!checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                                checkbox.prop('checked', 'true');
                                dateFieldForCheckbox.val('@(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())');
                                SaveEvaluation(function () { AlertSuccess('Executive signature successfully uploaded. Evaluation saved.'); });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (response != null) {
                            if (response.errorMessages != null) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < response.errorMessages.length; i++) {
                                    AlertError(response.errorMessages[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertError('Uploading Document Failed. Please contact your I.T. administrator.');
                        }
                    }
                    $('#upload-file-spinner').hide();
                    $('#upload-file-button').show();
                },
                async: true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Upon debugging the browser states the error occurred in *jquery* when it tries to send the XMLHttpRequest (the xhr.send line is the one blowing up)

```
            try {

                // Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
                xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
            } catch ( e ) {

                // #14683: Only rethrow if this hasn't been notified as an error yet
                if ( callback ) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
```

One of my coworkers stated that IIS can sometimes fight you when trying to pass large files to a server so I added this suggested code to my web config to no avail

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <!-- maxAllowedContentLength is in bytes (B)  -->
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20971520"/>
    <!-- 20MB -->
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

I suspect it's IIS screwing with me but to be frank I'm out of ideas. Please advise SO Community

Comment: did you install the service in IIS manager?

Comment: Yes, but the request never makes it to the server, which means the service is never involved in the bug. I should probably just remove that bit from the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you are not limited by the client on file sizes, rather it is almost always server-side. The defaults in IIS are rather low to prevent people from uploading files that run your server out of space. Think of the services that allow people to upload multi-gigabyte video files, for example; they wouldn't exist if browsers prevented those uploads to begin with.

What you have shown above is a correct usage of `FormData` to do an AJAX-enabled file upload.

For ASP.NET applications, you may also need to configure the `maxRequestLength` attribute of the `<httpRuntime>` node in your web.config. Note, this value is specified in **kilobytes** while the `maxAllowedContentLength` is specified in **bytes**.

All together, to allow file uploads up to 20MB, you should have these settings in your `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 20 MB specified in kilobytes -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- maxAllowedContentLength is in bytes (B)  -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20971520"/>
        <!-- 20MB -->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

To improve the user experience, you can check the size of the file before the upload begins by looking at the `file.size` property:

```
var file = $('#eval-attachment-modal-file')[0].files[0];
if (file && file.size <= 20971520) {
    // proceed with upload
} else {
    // file too large, show error
}
```